# Best way to implement a Pair class in Java

Tags: java, tuples

I have written the following code for a Pair class in Java using Map.Entry. Does anyone have any recommendations for improving it? The most important criteria for me that the class needed to meet were that it would be easy to construct a Pair and that .equals would work the way I wanted it to (equality of the two objects in the Pair in the same order means equality of the Pairs). The code seems to function as intended and is not used in anything that is taxing my system's memory yet, but any optimizations would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Pair {
    // Return a map entry (key-value pair) from the specified values
    public static <T, U> Map.Entry<T, U> of(T first, U second) {
        return new AbstractMap.SimpleEntry<>(first, second);
    }

    private Map.Entry entry;

    public Pair (Object x, Object y) {
        Set<Map.Entry> entries = new HashSet<>();
        entries.add(Pair.of(x, y));
        Object[] setArray = entries.toArray();
        this.entry = (Map.Entry) setArray[0];
    }

    public Object getKey() {
        return entry.getKey();
    }
    public Object getValue() {
        return entry.getValue();
    }


    @Override
    public boolean equals(Object o)
    {
        if (o instanceof Pair) {
            Pair pair = (Pair) o;
            return ( (entry.getKey().equals(pair.getKey())) && (entry.getValue().equals(pair.getValue())) );
        }
        return false;
    }

    @Override
    public int hashCode() {
            return Objects.hash(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue());
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
            return String.format( "(" +entry.getKey().toString() + ", " + entry.getValue().toString() + ")" );
    }
}
```

I have been considering using Collections.singletonMap instead of Map.Entry.

So far, I have successfully tested my code using the following:

```
import java.util.HashMap;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        HashMap<Pair, Integer> testMap = new HashMap<>();
        Pair onThrup = new Pair(1, 3);
        System.out.println(onThrup); //Prints contents of Pair, not hash
        testMap.put(onThrup, 7);
        Pair unoTres = new Pair(1, 3);
        System.out.println(onThrup.equals(unoTres));
        System.out.println(testMap.containsKey(onThrup));
        System.out.println(unoTres.hashCode() == onThrup.hashCode());
        System.out.println(testMap.containsKey(unoTres)); // Should be, and is, true
    }
}
```

Comment: I do want to be able to run a loop that constructs new Pairs while re-using the same variable name, like p, without issues. Equality of hashes and equality under .equals() should be based on the contents of the Pair so that running a HashMap.containsKey on a new Pair will return true if it has the same values as a Pair that was added as a key in a key-value pair to the HashMap earlier. I believe the code I have here does accomplish this, but if anyone has suggestions for formatting or efficiency, there may be a better way to write the class.

Comment: I think you could just use a field for each object the pair must hold. It will remove the need for Map.Entry. You also could use generics to make your class signature like `Pair<T1, T2>`. Anyway, I really do not see why you're using a set in pair constructor. It could be simplified.

Comment: And you must override equals and hashCode methods in Pair class if you want it to be usable as map key. You can look at [this tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/java-equals-hashcode-contracts) if you need to learn about it.

Comment: You can also use third-party Pair implementations - `ImmutablePair` from Apache Commons or `Tuple2` from Vavr

Comment: I used a Set because Entry is abstract and cannot be instantiated. 

I believe that the overrides of hashCode and equals were successful.

Comment: If I continue to use Map.Entry, should I use an implementing class like SimpleEntry or SimpleImmutableEntry to avoid the need for a Set?

Answer (score 2):

Java 16 includes [Record Classes](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10):

```
public record Pair<K, V>(K key, V value) {
    // intentionally empty
}
```

Creates a *class* with final fields, methods to retrieve `key` and `value`, `equals`, `hashCode` and `toString` methods.

Usage example:

```
var one = new Pair<Integer, String>(1, "one");
var two = new Pair(2, "two");
System.out.println(one);   // Pair[key=1, value=one]
if (!one.equals(two))
    System.out.printf("not same as Pair for %d%n", two.key());
```

<sup>not sure what is best, if available (java 16) I would use that</sup>

[JLS 8.10](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se16/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.10)
[JEP 395](https://openjdk.java.net/jeps/395)